# Statistics studio with python

Tags: python, statistics

I would like to do a statistics studio with python but my dataframe is with strings all data.

I don't know how I can continue, I did a basic studio count distinct of the name of the rows... but I would like to do a statistics studio or more interesting studio.

Could you give me any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

These packages could be interesting for you:

[pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/): Data manipulation and descriptive statistics

[statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html): statistic models